# Touchpad on Samsung N210 no ENTER on tap

Tags: touchpad

I Installed Loki 0.4 on my Samsung Netbook N210, all went well only when I tap the touchpad to ENTER, nothing hapens.
This was already so during installation. The Keys UNDER the touchpad do work.
(The left key can be used to ENTER)
Also vertical scrolling on the righthand side is not working.
Moving the cursor from the touchpad does work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Stupid newbee I am.
I went to SETTINGS, touchpad and set it to my needs. All fine.
Againg sorry to bother you!
Jan.